# Category Group id location in the control panel

Tags: categories, category-group

I cannot find the category group id number anywhere in the control panel since I upgraded to EE5. I am building a search based on cat group but I have no idea what the values are and cannot find them. Can some enlighten me to where they are listed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are in the EE Control Panel go to `Developer/Categories` page and select a Category Group in LH pane: the category group ID is then shown as the final element of the URL - if you are viewing category group 1, your URL will look a bit like this:

```
domain.com/admin.php?/cp/categories/group/1
```

It would be helpful if the group ID number appeared in a more visible place; maybe that will happen in some future version of EE, but for now that should get you home.

HTH

Comment: Great answer thanks for much , I never thought of looking in the URL